# WidgetProvider receives broadcast while there is no widget displayed

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

There is something I really don't understand with the Android Widget API.

I wrote a widget with a configuration Activity, and each time I install the application with adb, `WidgetProvider.onUpdate()` is called even if the widget isn't displayed. And also sometimes with multiple appWidgetIds, and also when the configuration Activity is started.

In the `onUpdate` method I checked the value of `appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds()`, and it returns 0 items.

```
public class FlickrWidget
    extends AppWidgetProvider
{

    /**
     * @see android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider#onUpdate(android.content.Context, android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager, int[])
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
    {
        Log.d( "FlickrWidget: Start onUpdate with " + appWidgetIds.length + " widgets" ); 

        int[] appWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds( new ComponentName( context, FlickrWidget.class ) );
        Log.d( "FlickrWidget: installed : " + appWidgetIds2.length + " widgets" ); //display 0 items
        for ( int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds2.length; i++ )
        {
            Log.d( "FlickrWidget : installed appWidgetId = " + appWidgetIds2[i] );
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++ )
        {
            Log.d( "FlickrWidget : appWidgetId = " + appWidgetIds[i] ); // can have multiple items
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand because I though :

1. An `AppWidgetProvider` receives the broadcast only when there is one ore more widget displayed.
2. A widget with a configuration `Activity` isn't updated with the broadcast on start up.
3. Calling `appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds()` in `onUpdate` should returns the same int array than the `appWidgetIds` in the parameters.

As I experiment all those 3 dots are false...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I repeated this question on Android Google Groups and a nice guy answers me that the Widget api documentation on developer.android.com is obsolete...

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/HfD-ojjsuso/discussion